# Mvvm wpf: update value binding before leaving focus of input element

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

I have this element in my xaml (DevExpress item):

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="False" EditValue="{Binding IDTIPOCONN}" 
     ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window},Path=DataContext.ttc}"  />
```

All the binding are correct, and when I change the value, I trigger some event from my ViewModel.

My problem is the update of the value is executed only when I leave the focus of my comboBox. I need, instead, to execute my action when the value is changed, before leaving its foucs.

How can I do it? I need this because selecting one or another from the list, I show to the user some hidden elements.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try for Binding set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`:

```
<dxe:ComboBoxEdit IsTextEditable="False"
                  EditValue="{Binding Path=IDTIPOCONN, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ... />
```

In this case, most likely the default value of [`UpdateSourceTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) is `LostFocus`.

Comment: Maybe UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus? :)

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov: Quote from question: `My problem is the update of the value is executed only when I leave the focus of my comboBox.`.

Comment: @AnatoliyNikolaev this is EXACTLY what I need! It works perfectly, simply and effective!!!